# Error when import readaFileSync from module fs in composable

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I have a composable called useReadFileUtils. I use this utility to read configuration file with some custom property settings. When I use the composable in my component in the script setup. I get this error that I'm confused about. I have included the script portion of the component.

```js
       //components/FileViewer.vue

       <script lang="ts" setup>  
           const { reader, readAll } = useReadFileUtils()     
       </script>


      // composables/useReadFileUtils.ts

      import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
      import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
      import  path  from 'path';

      const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
      const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);
      const RESOURCE_PROPS_PATH = '<path-to-resource>'

      const reader = () => {
       readFileSync( path.resolve(__dirname, RESOURCE_PROPS_PATH))
      }

      const readAll = (paths: string []) =>{
        //....omitted for brevity
      }

      export default () => {
    
        return {
            reader,
            readAll
        }    
      }
```

Unfortunately when I run the build, I get this error which I cannot fathom. I am extremely new to Nuxt/Vue so I do not know to begin to decipher this error.  Here is the error:

[11:20:53 PM]  ERROR  "readFileSync" is not exported by "__vite-browser-external", imported by "composables/useReadFileUtils.ts".

Comment: You should wrap this code with `if (process.server) { .... }` because `fs` and `path` (and other internal Node modules) are not supported by the browsers.

Comment: How can I move that code to the server? Is it possible to use composables on the server?

Comment: The `fs` runs on the server side. Are you open for a suggestion/alternative for it? If so, can you provide us an example of what type of file you are trying to read? Let me know

Comment: The wrapper `if (process.server)` will tell Nuxt that this code must be run only ruding SSR (server-side rendering) but not in the browser. The browser does not have (direct) access to the files on your server. All file operations must be performed during the building phase of your deployments.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to move it to the server side.